# Custom columns on edit-tags.php main page

Tags: custom-taxonomy, tags, columns

I am trying to add custom columns to edit-tags.php for a custom taxonomy that I have created.  This custom taxonomy is called equipment-types and it only applies to one custom post type called equipment. I am trying to use the same filters and actions that I would use to add custom columns on the edit.php page. I was able to actually create the custom columns with this filter:

```
add_filter('manage_edit-equipment-types_columns', 'define_equip_types_columns');
```

However, I cannot seem to populate these columns with any data. Normally, for the edit.php page I would use the following action:

```
add_action('manage_posts_custom_column', 'my_post_type_columns_content'));
```

And then within the my_post_type_columns_content function I would conditionally output column data based on the post-type.

The problem is I can't seem to find a similar hook for the edit-tags page. Adam Brown's website lists these hooks:

```
manage_blogs_custom_column

manage_comments_custom_column

manage_comments_nav

manage_link_custom_column

manage_media_custom_column

manage_media_media_column

manage_pages_custom_column

manage_plugins_custom_column

manage_posts_custom_column

manage_sites_custom_column

manage_themes_custom_column

manage_{$post->post_type}_posts_custom_column
```

None of which I think would be any help. Does anyone know of a way to do this? I'm so close, I have the columns created with titles, I just need to fill them with data!

EDIT: To be clear, I am not trying to make custom fields. I am trying to make custom COLUMNS in the table to the right on the main taxonomy page.

Regularly on the edit.php page where it displays All Posts for that post type I can make custom columns such as the quantity column like this:

> [image]

However, I don't think there is a hook to populate the columns on the edit-tags.php main page, even though I can create a custom column such as Image URL below:

> [image]

Comment: you mention in a comment that you got this to work. Would you mind updating this post, or better, providing another answer that lists how you do this for a custom taxonomy? Do it for the children.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this by hooking into the 'taxonomy'_edit_form and edited_'taxonomy' actions.

```
add_action('taxonomy_edit_form', 'foo_render_extra_fields');
function foo_render_extra_fields(){
    $term_id = $_GET['tag_ID'];
    $term = get_term_by('id', $term_id, 'taxonomy');
    $meta = get_option("taxonomy_{$term_id}");
    //Insert HTML and form elements here
}

add_action('edited_taxonomy', 'bar_save_extra_fields', 10, 2);
function bar_save_extra_fields($term_id){
    $form_field_1 = $_REQUEST['field-name-1'];
    $form_field_2 = $_REQUEST['field-name-2'];
    $meta['key_value_1'] = $form_field_1;
    $meta['key_value_2'] = $form_field_2;
    update_option("taxonomy_{$term_id}", $meta);
}
```

Make sure to change 'taxonomy' throughout the code example with your custom taxonomy. Be advised, this will only display on when a user edits a tag or category.

Update to add columns to the edit tags table:

```
function add_post_tag_columns($columns){
    $columns['foo'] = 'Foo';
    return $columns;
}
add_filter('manage_edit-post_tag_columns', 'add_post_tag_columns');

function add_post_tag_column_content($content){
    $content .= 'Bar';
    return $content;
}
add_filter('manage_post_tag_custom_column', 'add_post_tag_column_content');
```

This works like a charm! Here's a screenshot: http://3-3.me/lFdf

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't clear, this is not what I'm looking for. I know how to make custom fields for a taxonomy. I'm not trying to make custom fields. I'm trying to make custom COLUMNS in the table that is displayed on the edit-tags main page. There is a section to the left where you can add a new tag and then a section to the right with a table. I am trying to add custom columns to that table just as you would on the edit.php page for All Posts.

Comment: I understood you completely. My code does exactly what you are asking for, but only on the taxonomy term edit form. It's a bit wonky to add the fields to the main add taxonomy form.

I created an ad management plugin and had a custom taxonomy for adzones. I added fields to the taxonomy so I could give the user more options for their adzones. The fields again did not display on the main screen, only when the user edited a specific term.

Comment: I'm NOT talking about fields. There is no update_option involved. I already know how to do all of that stuff. I'll try to update my question with pics so you know what I'm talking about.

Comment: Also, to add fields to the main screen you can use the taxonomy_add_form_fields hook to place the fields within the default form or taxonomy_add_form to make a new form. To save these fields you can use the created_taxonomy hook.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood. I'll dig through the source to see what I come up with. :)

Comment: IV4 - Just updated the answer to give you what you need.

Comment: Yup that's it! That works for regular post tags. It took a little more digging for me to get it to work for custom post taxonomies but I got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Just for posterity, because I, like @IV4 still had a bit of wrangling to do with @Brian's answer to get it to work for a custom tax:

```
add_filter( "manage_{screen_id}_columns", "column_header_function" ) );  
add_action( "manage_{tax_slug}_custom_column",  "populate_rows_function"), 10, 3  );
```

So in my case, my custom taxonomy was "product-category", so it looked like this for me:

```
add_filter( "manage_edit-product-category_columns", array ( __CLASS__, "populate_edit_page_column_header" ) );  
add_action( "manage_product-category_custom_column",  array ( __CLASS__, "populate_edit_page_columns"), 10, 3  );
```

It should also be noted (though veterans will already know this) that for a taxonomy custom column you can ONLY create custom row data for columns that *are not defined by default.* The reason for this is that within the `WP_Terms_List_Table` class, unlike the way the `WP_Posts_List_Table` class works, the custom column action is *only* called through the `column_default` method, which is only invoked if the column name does not match one of the default columns defined in that class (cb, description, links, name, posts, slug).

In my case I wanted to modify the description column, but had to resort to creating a custom  column called 'summary' instead. Also note that custom columns would have to be added to the sort filter if you wanted to sort on that column (though sorting on a description column didn't make sense in my case).

In terms of the action's function signature, it can take up to 3 arguments, the first of which is actually useless (which makes me wonder how @Brian's answer worked at all):

```
function my_custom_columns( $value, $column, $term_id ){ }
```

Where `$value` is basically empty, `$column` is what you want to switch on and `$term_id` could be very important if you need to reference any data contained in your term!

Answer (score 0):

For adding on the main screen:

```
add_action( '<taxonomy-name>_add_form_fields', 'addfields' );
function addfields() {
    echo "<div class='form-field'><label>Wassup</label><textarea></textarea></div>";
}
```

For adding on individual term edit form:

```
add_action( '<taxonomy-name>_edit_form_fields', 'editfields' );
function editfields() {
    echo "<tr class='form-field'><th>Wassup</th><td><textarea></textarea></td></tr>";
}
```

I've tested this, it works. See the screens:

[image: taxo_add_form_fields],[image: taxo_edit_form_fields].

Replace `<taxonomy name>` with 'category' if you want this on the regular post categories. For saving the values wherever you want, you will need:

```
add_action( 'created_term',  'store_my_field' , '', 3 );
add_action( 'edit_term',  'store_my_field' , '', 3 );
```