# Can i add custom meta box (Media Uploader) at Category Description

Tags: uploads

I have Question how can i add custom meta box (Media Uploader) at category description, i mean when i will create or edit category then i can add any media file like PDF,

```
 <?php add_meta_box( $id, $title, $callback, $page, $context, $priority, $callback_args ); ?>
```

That is wordpress meta box function but i did not understand how can i use at category description, can any one help me to solve this.

Thanks

Umer

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using the plugin [Advanced Custom Fields](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields).

#### Config

[image: acf config]

#### Result

[image: acf result]

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can... check my answer here - [Custom columns on edit-tags.php main page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/28467/custom-columns-on-edit-tags-php-main-page/29773#29773), the screen shots have what you want.

Comment: This is a partial answer that has to be coupled with an actual upload field (see [this search query](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=%2Bupload+%2Bmeta_box)).